# Which one is the USB Hub speed?

Tags: kernel, drivers, usb

When doing `lsusb -v`

I got:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0424:2422 Standard Microsystems Corp. 

  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  ....
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
```

but `lsusb -t` shows:

```
Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 480M
```

Another example:

`lsusb -t`, the speed is 12M, it shows

```
Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
```

but in `lsusb -v`, it shows Full speed.

```
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0557:8021 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
 ....
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0557 ATEN International Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0x8021 Hub
  .....
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
```

I can't seem to match the speed statements of `lsusb -t` and `lsusb -v`.

Answer (score 0):

`lsusb -v` man page claims that it "**includes configuration descriptors for the device's *current* speed**" - but I don't know how to make sense of this in the output. Hopefully someone else can help.

> "*Which one is the USB Hub speed?*"

That would be `lsusb -t`.
`lsusb -t` shows the ***supported*** speeds using the tree hierarchy option.
And the USB supported speeds vary between versions:

```
USB 1.10    12Mb/s
USB 2.00    480Mb/s
USB 3.00    5Gb/s
```